# How to get ip or hostname of Ansible server in jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

How do I get the IP or hostname of Ansible server in a jinja2 template? I'm talking about the IP of Ansible control machine, not the ip of the target servers, e.g. `{{ ansible_fqdn }}`

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have gathered facts for localhost. Do this in a seperate play in your playbook if needed. The following should be sufficient:

   ```
   - name: Simply gather facts for localhost
     hosts: localhost
     gather_facts: true
   ```
2. Use the var from localhost in your template i.e. `{{ hostvars['localhost'].ansible_fqdn }}`